# Values in parenthesis does not evaluate in scheme

Tags: scheme, lisp

I want to return the values equal to 2. If equal to 2 then "`true`", if not equal to 2 then "`false`" , if not a number then "`not`". Below is my code snippet.

```
(define (test mList)
    (if (null? mList)
        '()
        (let ((x (car mList))
                (y (cdr mList)))
        (if (number? x)
            (cond ((= x 2) (cons "true" (test y)))
              ((list? x) (append (test x)
                                    (test y)))
            (else (cons "false" (test y))))
        (cons "not" (test y))))))
```

`(display (test '(b a (2 b) 9 2 2 g)))` returns `(not not not false true true not)`. The value in parenthesis `(2 b)` evaluate as one then return `not`.

How the output will be like this.
`(not not true not false true true not)`.

What did I missed?

Comment: `(if (number? x) (cond ... ((list? x) ...) ...) ...)` - If `x` is a number, it cannot be a list.

Comment: I've reverted the edit since the question without the code made no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code with some comments that might shed some lights on why you don't recurse lists in your list:

```
(define (test lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      '()                                          ; lst is null
      (let ((a (car lst))                          ; lst is not null
            (d (cdr lst)))
        (if (number? a)
            (cond ((= a 2) (cons "true" (test d))) ; if a is a number and equal to 2
                  ((list? a) (append (test a)      ; if a is a number and not equal to 2 and a list at the same time
                                     (test d)))
                  (else (cons "false" (test d))))  ; if a is a number and not equal to 2 and not a list
            (cons "not" (test d))))))              ; a is not a number
```

I've renamed some variables here, but it does the same.

The code that checks if the element is a list is the consequent on the previous test that it is a number. Since a number cannot be a list your lists end up as the alternative where you add "not" to your list.

The list `(2 b)` is not a number so it is perfectly within your specification:

> If equal to 2 then "true", if not equal to 2 then "false" , if not a
>   number then "not"

The code that handles sublists is correct if it predicate and consequence were moved to the alternative of `(number? a)`. Eg.

```
(cond 
  ((list? a) <do list stuff>)             ; a is perhaps a list
  ((not (number? a)) <not number stuff>)  ; a is not a list, perhaps number?
  ((= a 2) <do 2 stuff>)                  ; a not list and is number, perhaps 2?
  (else <do number not 2 stuff>))         ; a is not list and is number and not 2
```

Notice I've reordered it a little sincethis way it's ok that the previous tests were false and that allows for a flatter case analysis.